# ajax not working showing forbidden error

Tags: apache, cakephp, lamp

Hi this is my ajax code

```
$("#ajax_login_form").on('submit',function(event){            
   var dataString = $("#ajax_login_form").serialize();           
   $.post('http://myshowcam.com//users/login', dataString, function(response){  }, 'json');  
});
```

After submitting the form i get below error in my console.

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /TestSite/users/login on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at myshowcam.com Port 80

Please help.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Quickly, why are you using `//` in the post url `http://myshowcam.com//users/login`. Then Check your apache host configuration or post the content here in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you  Andre Santiago 20.I think the problem is due to apache host configuration as you mentioned above.But i don't know what  to check.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. That makes it more difficult then. Knowing how to configure apache is extremely crucial.

Assuming you are using CakePHP 3, try following instructions here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#apache. This file is generally located at `/etc/httpd/conf/http.conf`.

Best approach is to use `virtual_hosts` which the location of that file could be created here `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`. For example, you could have `myshowcam.com.conf` there. There are plenty of VirtualHosts example here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html